# Using PROGMEM to save RAM

Tags: arduino-uno

I am successful putting and retrieving a char array into Arduino flash memory using [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/) char arrays.

I am building my application using header files with a class definition / implementation and would like to keep the strings in the same header file.

If I define another PROGMEM char array neither one can be executed. In other words, these PROGMEM are global arrays as far as the Arduino compiler is concerned. They compile, but they won't show up.

Here is my test code:

```
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(*strFlashDebug[0]);  // in CDebug
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(*strFlashTrack[0]);  // in CTrack
```

If I put both definitions in the same header file, it only works with only one *lcd.print* enabled, not commented out.

It appears that multiple PROGMEM arrays can be defined and compiled, but only one is actually usable. What is the explanation?

Comment: Please post your array definitions as well, or better even, a complete compilable example with just enough code to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to know for PROGMEM is that [the AVR chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATmega328#Family) you’re using does not have a single flat address space. I.e., it does not use a [von Neumann architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture); instead, it uses a specific version of what is known as a [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture): it has separate address spaces for RAM, program memory, and EEPROM. All of them start at 0. Which means that while dereferencing a null pointer is technically still undefined behavior in C++, it can be (and often is) perfectly valid in Arduino code.

The short version is: If you have a PROGMEM pointer, whatever function you pass it to must work on PROGMEM pointers. `lcd.print` does not, and as far as I can tell there isn't any way the function could possibly detect this is not a RAM pointer. You have to call a different function, assuming there is one in the first place.

See *[PROGMEM](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM)* (Arduino reference) for examples on how to use PROGMEM data.

Comment: To add to this excellent description, you could, as a workaround, temporarily copy to RAM the PROGMEM data you need to pass to `lcd.print()` and pass it this copy. A wrapper function, say `lcd_print_PMEM()` could encapsulate the details, and the RAM used would literally only be allocated for the duration of that call.

Answer (score 0):

A PROGMEM variable definition (i.e., declaration) allocates memory in FLASH. You need use an *extern* clause in the header file and a physical declaration in the C code which is linked in your code. It's pays also for potential static class properties.

Also check if *lcd.print()* accepts a PROGMEM array, i.e., if the overloaded procedure is defined and called.

Just note I recommend using much more effective string formatting via file streams (FILE) and *fprintf_P()*.